# TypeScript - is it possible validate string types based on pattern matching or even length?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

Consider the following component, which uses a library called `styled-components` to create a prestyled `Text` component:

```
const StyledText = styled(Text)`
  font-family: Roboto;
  color: ${(props: ITextProps) => props.color || '#000' }; 
`
```

where `ITextProps` is:

```
interface ITextProps {
  color: string;
}
```

Is there a way to enforce that only valid hex strings are passed to my component?

Ideally the color prop should always match the pattern `/#\d{3}(\d{3})?/g`, a # followed by at least 3 digits and optionally 3 more digits. If that's not possible, then is there a way to at least enforce that the string is either 4 or 7 characters long?

My research has brought me to a dead end so I'm wondering if anyone on SO might know how I can implement this behavior in TypeScript.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579#issuecomment-261519733 and from that point on there is more conversation regarding regex as type

Comment: Here is an implementation for one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68064202/how-to-type-a-color-prop/68068969#68068969

Answer (score 12, accepted):

2021-06-13: Updated for TS4.1+

---

Not truly at compile-time, no.  There is a [suggestion (now at microsoft/TypeScript#41160)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41160) to allow regular-expression validated string types, but it's not clear that it will ever be implemented.  If you want to go to that suggestion and give it a  and describe a compelling use case that isn't already listed, it couldn't hurt (but it probably won't really help either).

You could *try* to use [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) for this to programmatically generate a big [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) which matches every acceptable string literal.  This even kind of works if you only need three-ish digits:

```
type UCaseHexDigit = '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | 
  '8' | '9' | 'A' | 'B' | 'C' | 'D' | 'E' | 'F'
type HexDigit = UCaseHexDigit | Lowercase<UCaseHexDigit>
type ValidThreeDigitColorString = `#${HexDigit}${HexDigit}${HexDigit}`;
// type ValidThreeDigitColorString = "#000" | "#001" | "#002" | "#003" | "#004" | "#005" 
// | "#006" |  "#007" | "#008" | "#009" | "#00A" | "#00B" | "#00C" | "#00D" | "#00E" 
// | "#00F" | "#00a" | "#00b" | "#00c" | "#00d" |  // "#00e" 
// | ... 10626 more ... | "#fff"
```

but since such template literal types can only handle unions on the order of tens-of-thousands of members, this will break if you try to do this with six digits:

```
type ValidSixDigitColorString =
    `#${HexDigit}${HexDigit}${HexDigit}${HexDigit}${HexDigit}${HexDigit}`; // error!
//  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent
```

So you'll have to use a workaround.

---

One workaround is to use template literal types as a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) *constraint* instead of making `ValidColorString` a concrete type.  Instead, have a type like `AsValidColorString<T>` that takes a string-type `T` and *checks* it to see if it's valid.  If it is, it is left alone.  If not, then return a valid color string that is "close" to the bad one.  For example:

```
type ToHexDigit<T extends string> = T extends HexDigit ? T : 0;
type AsValidColorString<T extends string> =
    T extends `#${infer D1}${infer D2}${infer D3}${infer D4}${infer D5}${infer D6}` ?
    `#${ToHexDigit<D1>}${ToHexDigit<D2>}${ToHexDigit<D3>}${ToHexDigit<D4>}${ToHexDigit<D5>}${ToHexDigit<D6>}` :
    T extends `#${infer D1}${infer D2}${infer D3}` ?
    `#${ToHexDigit<D1>}${ToHexDigit<D2>}${ToHexDigit<D3>}` :
    '#000'

const asTextProps = <T extends string>(
   textProps: { color: T extends AsValidColorString<T> ? T : AsValidColorString<T> }
) => textProps;
```

It's pretty complicated; mostly it splits apart the string `T` and inspects each character, converting bad ones into `0`.  Then, instead of annotating something as `TextProps`, you call `asTextProps` on it for validation:

```
const textProps = asTextProps({
    color: "#abc" // okay
})

const badTextProps = asTextProps({
    color: "#00PS1E" // error
//  ~~~~~
//  Type '"#00PS1E"' is not assignable to type '"#00001E"'.(2322)
})
```

This works at compile time, but might be more trouble than it's worth.

---

Finally, you can fall back to pre-TS4.1 solution and make a nominal-ish subtype of `string` with a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to narrow `string` values to it... and then jump through all sorts of hoops to use it:

```
    type ValidColorString = string & { __validColorString: true };

    function isValidColorString(x: string): x is ValidColorString {
      const re = /#[0-9a-fA-F]{3}([0-9a-fA-F]{3})?/g; // you want hex, right?
      return re.test(x);
    }
```

Usage:

```
    const textProps: ITextProps = {
      color: "#abc"
    }; // error, compiler doesn't know that "#abc" is a ValidColorString
    
    const color = "#abc";
    if (isValidColorString(color)) {
      const textProps2: ITextProps = {
        color: color
      }; // okay now
    } else {
      throw new Error("The world has ended");
    }
```

The latter isn't perfect, but it at least gets you a bit closer to enforcing such constraints.

Hope that gives you some ideas; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useDefineForClassFields=true#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAVCYYBsQBcIBkBLPAJxEwDERDMkBvAKCWaRwE8ZkBVAYRCggAJCAA8AIoQDmxJAF4kAcgAMCpAB9FARlUaFAJh2KAzIYUAWUwFZTANlMB2UwA5TATlMBBUwCFTPU2KmAKKmFApMLOycSMLiUjLyvPxCohLSOOpI+AD2AO4QJPDJADxJArFpxAB8EcxRyABq5IQAJigAFiQQEJU4PNmY2SQAyjgkhMCSckgABgDEACR0FfE4AL5LK+kby6mrazMA3LVIAPSnrByNzW2d3b39gyNjE1PyAERzSt-vmZ-fml+Gn+Sj0QKQIKM4JBZmhXyUljh3xs4JO5wh8PsSKUTmxrmxHmx3mxPGxYmxQWxFGxIGxACNUSwzhcQfBsS1wcyMd8IOCAHQCpCaJQ2PQ2JBgIbIAV8v5zABmiveDBO9SQTUwrWGhDi6UeQ1G40mchOTPmmz22wtuuIOy2tutvTtloduxt6yOXIKJCGAEI0RckAA-EOhsPhiORqPRmOx0MBpBBEQwLpQKCEbLAJAp7ItACuiCgSBASDzwAzWbVOHauCQhCLOGy2SQ8GyGEwolYza6KegEGAOAYaxVoEgsAQyDQ7dwBGIBXI-WAUDG1AH9FVVyQZRS7umylM2ky+lMJiPFiP1iPdiPjiPLiP7iPXiPviP-iPgSPISPYQ30XtGSJHw5QuhkGg5PkhQlNuAE1H+k7ZABxQoEgoh4MALRFsuRqSFU0woWh-aYTEoFIAA-KgSAAFxIEoxxMmqHhQBqrT6s8OHIahIjocR2GvHhsimiwBHcURRbmnQEzygUSBiJoOxSTJYh6ApwDSSQslGKp6myWY2lKZY+kaWINgHORQnMBJKCIaBxRyVUOzWUhykOUsTm2WIRiuXQ7nunZZjeb5vR2ZYgU2X5JkOTM1EWZRhEYeJiySWpSnyUsinGSp6UpcZWnRWRsVWeFwX2Y5xWrHZehhc5XlmVRsUKPCKgqkyrZLhk-BoNxAAKPowEW8icfFvEvJMVQABR4D1fVQDRdAtgMQw0SJPFFkxLEtGxhqvMheEUShNHrTcW2jZIu1IGsACUch4VNOC9dk-XHCcbXLqwaEPf10ydR9M3jYwTKtYtJA0Z8IB0myXLZAA1iAbAnFdLUsK9GR0iAbS-Y9A3FlAXX3X9AOA8wrZPKD8LdcMmiUl6JA+iQCbBmGDMoJuCgghTVPvKo9ZIMA2QdWmUigHSHZdpc0Rs01SicwofLjXoRh6Hol0IyrQ4qgwo7QHAiBIAAcm2EzkAAklA7Trgxm4bSdOHTHxxoAGT0EgAD6LsAG7HcD22TDRYx5sgazPUyEykPKE5IMbeOfUWhNEyTS3ql7Tw+5I9EsMOSPMPKZbwDgFZ1sxycGqd40iDR9uSJdNEiIXSeapt3unRbRMLe1SBdNMpxzAA2koAC0rggP38oeP3FAALp0Fp4194Pw+j+PU9aZdZGnGnXJsNkeZILkIBru0ogADQd1I7Q4AVrcdxAOB5iQWZdHyeDLmXl3p8wmdA+3d0xzRUeY19eQcdAYJxBhicGbIEaHBpnTE+rYMA0Bki0bI0BgAKAyNDPmuRWA1gyGDCGvweYlmtk3HCWc25vVAdMfBbJ351nlEgca9YSEp1LqAy611gFfzej-Gaeg-7RxmtMLhrdQE0VAbFIOUNYZsF5nkBGqFMACBbkTasPpsHAAgNgoItMhjjXeB0ZAuQhiYBaEgGsRYiIQA5G-BGKpM5AA)

Comment: hm that's a shame but I guess it's better than nothing. Ultimately I think this is inappropriate for my use case but I appreciate the info and examples nonetheless.