# Should I test all component props?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

For example, I have component like this:

```js
const Button = ({borderColor, children}) => {
  return (
    <button style={{borderColor: borderColor ? `border: 1px solid ${borderColor}` : null}}>
      {children}
    </button>
  )
}
```

Main goals of this component are:

- pass children prop further
- handle custom border color

With children - it's usual situation. But with css I don't know, should I test it, or not.

Some articles about RTL tell that we don't have to test css. But
in my opinion, in this case, our css prop is important for end user
(e.g. some other developer who will use this component) and this css
should be tested. What's the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing a React Application should be about behaviors. That is, how the application behaves when controlled by an end user. That's one of [the guiding principles of react-testing-library](https://testing-library.com/docs/guiding-principles), and one I agree with.

Therefore, going by this statement you can do two different things:

- Test the complete behavior that causes the border color to change. That is  [Integration Testing](https://medium.com/expedia-group-tech/integration-testing-in-react-21f92a55a894)
- Type check the component to guarantee that you cannot pass an incorrect value for `borderColor`. That is [Unit Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing)

*In my opinion* with this use case, testing anything else would be testing React itself or, as the other answer noted, you ability to write a correct css string. The later can be tested with your own eyes anyway and isn't likely to change

---

### Type checking example

Giving you an example for integration testing is hard to do without knowing your complete use case. As for type checking you have two options:

- Using [PropTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)
- Switching to [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)

**Note**: These options aren't equivalent. Proptypes is a library that checks the props at *runtime* with a developement build. They are ignored with a production build. Typescript on the other hand is a complete compiler, that runs during the *build*. The correct solution depends on your setup

#### With PropTypes

You can use `PropTypes.oneOf` :

```js
Button.propTypes  = {
 // Edit as needed
 borderColor: PropTypes.oneOf(["red", ,blue"])
}
```

#### Typescript

```js
interface ButtonProps {
 borderColor: "blue" | "red";
}

const Button: React.FunctionComponent<ButtonProps> = ({borderColor, children}) => {...}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. 
From my opinion, all props accepted by component should be tested. 
In situtation with styles (borderColor) - it's not some static internal css of component, it's dynamic styles coming from outside and their behaviour should be correct.

For example, if I leave only type checking and suddenly remove border style from button - tests will be correct anyway but component wouldn't display border.
What to do in this situatuin? Or maybe there is can be some trade-off?

Comment: I agree that all props accepted by a component should be "tested", otherwise a React code base can quickly become un maintainable. Now, I think that type checking is enough of a test. If your remove the border style and your using the typescript version from my answer, you'll get a compilation error. If you're using propTypes you'll get a runtime warning. In both cases the *integration test* should fail anyway because the dynamic styling will cease to work.

Comment: To clarify what I mean by "integration test", if for exemple your borderColor changes to red when the button is selected, you should *definitely* write a test that reproduces this behavior. `react-testing-library`  allows you to do that easily by emulating the click, en verifying that the element's color has changed. You can even use some kind of Test Driven Development flow with react-testing-library

Comment: I mean some other moment that ts can't prevent. In situation when I still pass 'borderColor' prop to the component, but for example, inside component I changed implementation (suddenly) and now my button doesn't have this border <button>{children}</button> (but React component still accepting props for it) 
And without tests - I can't get alert that something went wrong.
Sorry for maybe some stuppied moments from my side, but I just confused a little bit)

Comment: Ha I see what you mean ! Well first of all if your're not using the prop at all, depending on your `tsconfig`, typescript should raised an `unused variable` error. However if you're just changing the behavior inside your Button component, indeed you need a test do detect the change. However as stated in my answer I believe integration tests are better suited for this task, but that is up for debate and outside the scope of this question IMHO.

Comment: Thanks again. This "Button" component is just an example. I'm just learning tests and think that in the future will create some tests for styling only in situations when this style is connected with some props, or very important for the component (like 'position: fixed' for Modal).
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Potentially misreading your question, but maybe you're only asking because `"is this string a valid CSS color"` feels like a silly or annoying detail to test, even though you're aware of the problems that not writing tests will have on other developers who will use this component.

Is this a silly thing to test? I agree *conditionally*.

IMO this is far better solved using Typescript to enforce constraints on what form the string can take. Some ideas here: [TypeScript - is it possible validate string types based on pattern matching or even length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54674576/typescript-is-it-possible-validate-string-types-based-on-pattern-matching-or-e)

A better thing to test is probably a functionality question like "does this component genuinely create a button wrapping the children with the 1px solid borderColor that we asked for?

In that case, yes I'd write a test for that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a visual regression testing tool like Chromatic to help with testing visual changes based on props.